# How to vertical allign list items with icons

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Can someone help me understand how can I vertical align this?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hds9pxzf/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.css"
></link>

<aside class="menu column is-2 full-height">
    <ul class="menu-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="">
            <i class="mdi mdi-file-document-box mdi-48px"></i>
            <span>Document</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="">
            <i class="mdi mdi-file-document-box mdi-48px"></i>
            <span>Document</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

I need align icon and text next to it?
there is some more css since I'm using bulma.io and something custom but not so relevant I think

You can delete that css and create new one if it is not ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few options at your disposal, depending on your needs.

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/hds9pxzf/1/)

Use `display: inline-block;` on the element(s) that are next to each other and need to be aligned.  Then you can use `vertical-align: [top|middle|baseline]` as needed for each element

```
i, span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If that alignment doesn't work for you, then you should set the `vertical-align` to `top`, to get them positioned how you like, and then you can use `line-height` to fine-tune the vertical positioning of each element.  Example:

```
i, span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

i {
    line-height: 39px;
}

span {
    line-height: 39px;
}
```

Comment: interesting, since I tried that same code set only on span element and it's not working. But if I use it on <i> element it works no problem. But just in case I set it on both. Thnaks

Comment: Yes, for maximum control, `inline-block` should be on both elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` rules to `li a`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/6askvkzv/)

```css
aside {
  background-color: #0067ad;
  height: 100%;
}

li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-list {
  list-style: none;
}

i {
  color: white;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
.router-link-active {
  background-color: black;
}

span {
  color: white;
}


}
a {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<aside class="menu column is-2 full-height">
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="">
        <i class="mdi mdi-file-document-box mdi-48px"></i>
        <span>Document</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="">
        <i class="mdi mdi-file-document-box mdi-48px"></i>
        <span>Document</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```